# Compare two arrays and return value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
Array
(
    [1] = 1575255
    [2] = 1575258
)

Array
(
    [Aantal kleuren opdruk] = Array
        (
            [1575252] = 1 kleur
            [1575253] = 2 kleuren
            [1575254] = 3 kleuren
            [1575255] = 4 kleuren
        )

    [Opdrukpositie] = Array
        (
            [1575256] = Borst
            [1575258] = Borst en rug
            [1575257] = Rug
        )

)
```

How can I compare the value of array 2 with the value of array 1 in their current order?

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: To have an array with the values of array 1 matching the values of array 2

Comment: paste the desired result and your attempt of fixing it

Comment: do you want something like this:- https://eval.in/657090  ?  i have taken array because it quite opossible that same index will be there in more than one-sub-array of second array, and they both have different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) :

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    $arr[] = array_column($arr2 ,$value);
}

print_r($arr);
```

assuming that the first array is $arr1 and the second is $arr2

**EDIT**

the one line solution using array_column and array_map

```
$arr = array_map(function($value) use ($arr2) {return array_column($arr2, $value);} ,$arr1);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Nice, one more thing could we also use the keys from array2?

Comment: in the first solution using foreach , you only will need to use $value as a key for the new array,
 `$arr[$value] = array_column($arr2 ,$value);`

Comment: From array 2 I mean, the text

Comment: i think you will have to do more complicated loops or make a good use of array_walk or array_map to get your desired result .

Answer (score 0):

OK so the first array has this. Take it as `$a`:

```
  $a = ["1575255", "1575258"];
  $second = ["Aantal kleuren opdruk" => [
        "1575252" => "1 kleur",
        "1575253" => "2 kleuren",
        "1575254" => "3 kleuren",
        "1575255" => "4 kleuren"
    ],
    "Opdrukpositie" => [
        "1575256" => "Borst",
        "1575258" => "Borst en rug",
        "1575257" => "Rug"
              ]
    ];
   foreach($second as $val){
     foreach($val as $key => $v){
      if(in_array($key, $a)){
         echo $v."<br>";
      }
    } 
   }
```

Comment: @CoenPonsen Glad to help. :)